# How to set different ( text size and text color ) on two line text on button widget

Tags: android, html

I have a single button with two text on it (Consider Ok and Done by using 
 tag from html)and I want to set different text color for that button(Ok=yellow , Done=Red ) with different size (Ok="20sp" Done="30sp")
How to implement it by using HTML code in Android ....

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
.ok { color: yellow; font-size: 20px; }
.done { color: red; font-size: 30px; }
</style>
<button><span class=ok>Ok</span><br><span class=done>Done</span></button>
```

I have assumed that “sp” means pixels, `px`. If it means points, use `pt` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply.... But as I have said that, I have used "HTML code" to make my button with two text with different color! I need an HTML code for setting two color for same button with different text size!!!

Comment: This would be clearer if you showed the HTML code you have used, but assuming you really want to use HTML only here (I don’t see why), the best show is probably `<button><font color=yellow size=4>Ok</font><br><font color=red size=6>Done</font></button>`. The meanings of `size` values are implementation-dependent, but that’s all you can do in plain HTML.